# Azure Bicep - Conditionally create a secret

Tags: infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I'm creating a KeyVault with Bicep and I want to create a secret in the vault, but only when there's no secret yet with the given name.

Checking if the KeyVault exists wasn't working, so I'm checking now if certain tag exists.
When creating the Vault I write a tag in the resource group. Afterwards I change the secret's password in the script and I run the script again, expecting the old password isn't overwritten. Unfortunately the secret is being recreated with the new password.

Any idea how to do a condition in Bicep, based on the existence of certain resource?

```
resource keyvault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' = {
    name: name
    ...
}

var rgWithDefaultTag = {
  tags: {
    keyVaultSecretName: ''
  }
}

// Only create a new secret when a new KeyVault is created.
resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-04-01-preview' = if (empty(union(rgWithDefaultTag, resourceGroup()).tags['keyVaultSecretName'])) {
  name: '${keyvault.name}/MySecret'
  properties: {
    value: 'value'
  }
}

resource tag 'Microsoft.Resources/tags@2021-01-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    tags: {
      keyVaultSecretName: secret.name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you output the result of the entire if clause and the union part?

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce the problem - for me it works. When tag is set, secret is not overwritten. Deleting the tag will put a new value into the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead. It checks if the given tag exists on the resource group.

```
resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = if (!contains(resourceGroup()).tags, 'keyVaultSecretName')) {
...
```